# Relative paths break when executing Python script from Windows batch?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, relative-path

My Python script works perfectly if I execute it directly from the directory it's located in.  However if I back out of that directory and try to execute it from somewhere else (without changing any code or file locations), all the relative paths break and I get a `FileNotFoundError`.

The script is located at `./scripts/bin/my_script.py`.  There is a directory called `./scripts/bin/data/`.  Like I said, it works absolutely perfectly as long as I execute it from the same directory... so I'm very confused.

**Successful Execution** (*in* `./scripts/bin/`): `python my_script.py`

**Failed Execution** (*in* `./scripts/`): Both `python bin/my_script.py` and `python ./bin/my_script.py`

**Failure Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/my_script.py", line 87, in <module>
    run()
  File "./bin/my_script.py", line 61, in run
    load_data()
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\scripts\bin\tables.py", line 12, in load_data
DATA = read_file("data/my_data.txt")
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\scripts\bin\fileutil.py", line 5, in read_file
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/my_data.txt'
```

**Relevant Python Code**:

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in file]
        return [line for line in lines if len(line) == 0 or line[0] != "#"]

def load_data():
    global DATA
    DATA = read_file("data/my_data.txt")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is logical. The files are relative to your working directory. You change that by running the script from a different directory. 
What you could do is take the directory of the script you are running at run time and build from that.

```
import os

def read_file(filename):
    #get the directory of the current running script. "__file__" is its full path
    path, fl = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    #use path to create the fully classified path to your data
    full_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    with open(full_path, "r") as file:
       #etc
```

Comment: Is it not supposed to be relative to the *script*'s location... ?

Comment: it also has nothing to do with windows. same behavior on *nix.

Answer (score 2):

Your resource files are relative to your script.  This is OK, but you need to use

```
os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

or

```
os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

to obtain the directory where the script is located.  Then use `os.path.join()` or other function to generate the paths to the resource files.